# Custom Exception Handler doesn't get invoked

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I've been using custom exception handler to alter the default behavior while raising ValidationError, since i need to get user-friendly message **in json** instead 500 status code and html page.
**However**, im faced with **an issue**, **that handler does not even get invoked**.
The path to handler is specified correctly in **settings.py**:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'api.utils.exception_handler.handler',
}
```

Part of the **handler** function in **exception_handler.py**:

```
def handler(exc, context):
  response = exception_handler(exc, context)
  ...
```

Part of the **post** method in **APIView class**:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      serializer = UserMiniSerializer(data=request.data)
      if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
        ...
```

Part of the **Validate** method of **UserMiniSerializer**:

```
def validate(self, attrs):
   ...
   if not user.check_password(password):
            raise ValidationError({'password': 'Invalid password. Please, try again.'})
   ...
```

I've tried to handle ValidationError with try-except block in post method, however i think there is a better solution.
**Thanks**.

Answer (score 0):

Had a bug related to raise_exception=True.
(solved)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).